# MySQL CREATE statement in MSSQL : the KEY keyword?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have SQL CREATE statements for MySQL. They have KEY.

Example :

```
CREATE TABLE a (
  a varchar(25) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  b varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  KEY location (a)
);
```

What is the CREATE statement for this table in MSSQL ? The KEY keyword does cause problem.

Comment: KEY is synonyme for INDEX in MySQL

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE database1.dbo.a (
  a nvarchar(25),
  b nvarchar(25),
)
GO

CREATE INDEX a_index
  ON database1.dbo.a(a)
GO
```

...change db and schema names

Answer (score 2):

if key is the column name, you could use square brackets to surround it..and then run the sql statement, like this:
[KEY]

Comment: Normal column name don't have to be in bracklets

Comment: Thanks for your help anyway Ovais Khatri.